# Does adjusting an object's model property within a view controller break MVC design?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

Will i  break MVC-pattern design if i choose to modify an object's model property within a view controller?

for example, **ZZQuery** is a model used in **ZZViewController**, declared as property ***zQuery**. I want to see if **zQuery** contains *propertyA*, and if so - mark **zQuery's** *boolA* as **YES**.

```
 if (self.zQuery.propertyA)
        {
            self.zQuery.boolA = YES;
        }
```

does the code above break MVC design? or am I allowed to modify zQuery without breaking design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion a view controller should only update the model in response to user interaction with the view.  If, for example, you have a boolean in the model and the user changes a switch on the view that is tied to this boolean then the view controller can update the model to reflect the user input.

In your example the change to the model is based on "business logic", so the model shouldn't be changed by the view controller.  The relationship between `propertyA` and `boolA` should be managed by the model.